# ¿Cómo usar vue2.leaflet.markercluster en un proyecto Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js

Estoy tratando de usar [vue2.leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/jperelli/vue2-leaflet-markercluster) en un proyecto nuxt pero al usar el componente, en la consola da el error

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

codigo:

```
<template>
    <div id="map" style="height: 100vh">
        <client-only>
           <l-map>
           <l-tile-layer></l-tile-layer>
           <v-marker-cluster>
               <v-marker v-for="c in elements" v-if="c.id !== null" :lat-lng="c.latlon">
                   <v-popup :content="c.tooltipContent"></v-popup>
               </v-marker>
           </v-marker-cluster>
           </l-map>
      </client-only>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster from "vue2-leaflet-markercluster"
export default {
    "elements": [{/*elements*/}]
}
</script>
```

Comment: El error te indica que no has registrado alguno de los componentes que estas utilizando ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código donde haces el "export default components"?. [Aca un ejemplo](https://github.com/jperelli/vue2-leaflet-markercluster/blob/master/example.vue)

Answer (score 0):

En nuxt.js es necesario hacer algunos pasos adicionales para utilizar cualquier dependencia, todo esto gracias al sistema de plugins de nuxt.js.

Lo primero que tendiras que hacer es instalar la dependencia por npm o yarn.

```
npm install --save vue2-leaflet-markercluster
```

Una vez la hallas instalado procederemos a crear un plugin.

Nota: los plugins deberian crearce en una carpeta encontrada en la raiz del proyecto llamada plugins

En este caso vamos a importarlo de forma global para que ya no tengas problemas de importacion. sin embargo puedes importalo localmente utilizando vue.use

```
// plugins/leaflet.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster from 'vue2-leaflet-markercluster'
Vue.component('v-marker-cluster', Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster)
```

ó

```
// plugins/leaflet.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster from 'vue2-leaflet-markercluster'
Vue.use(Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster)
```

Este plugin le indica a nuxt.js la forma en la que quieres utilizar tu dependencia.

Cuando crees el plugin solo tendras que registrarlo en nuxt.config y eso sera todo ya podras importar este componente en cualquier parte del proyecto

```
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/leaflet.js', mode: 'client' }, // only on clientside
  ]
}
```

Nota: Cuando importes el plugin pudes importarlo en dos modos, server o client, esto dependera del tipo de dependencia que utilizas. La mayoria de las dependencias de vue no soportan el modo server entonces te recomiendo siempre utilizarla con client a menos de que tenga su implementacion para nuxt.

finalmente usalo asi en el archivo de vue:

```
export default {
...
  components: {
    'v-marker-cluster': Vue2LeafletMarkerCluster
  ...
  },
...
}
```

Cuentame si pude ayudarte. Saludos.